# Tapestry event dynamic components

Tags: java, event-handling, tapestry

I want to implement an eventhandler for a component, which is dynamically generated. That means I have a `Table`, whichs source is bound to a custom `TableModel` (which implements an interface `JsonGenerator`, with which the json data can be generated). In this `TableModel`, I add a few custom components, which fire an event (`valueChanged`) when their state changes. Those components have ids (1 to 4). However, I can't just add a method similiar to this:

```
void onValueChangedFrom1 ()
```

as there are times when no component with the id 1 exists. I'd get the following exception when trying anway:

```
Method de.[...].onValueChangedFrom1() references component id '1' which does not exist.
```

I can't modify the custom `TableModel`, the `JsonGenerator` nor the other custom components.

It might be interesting to know that the values of the custom components can be accessed via the `Request` service of tapestry like that:

```
request.getParameter("1");
```

But how can I add an event handler when this value changes? Is this even possible in Tapestry?

Comment: Can't you have a shared event handler `onValueChanged` without specifying the `FromXXX`? In this case it will handle all events from all components in hierarchy. If necessary you could inspect `request.getParameter("1")` and handle events differently based on its value.

Comment: @DmitryGusev whilst trying your suggestion, I realized that the component which fires the event isn't even instantiated. I don't quite understand how it's being displayed anyways, but that's the reason the event handling doesn't work. Otherwise your solution seems to do it's job.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the 1-4 as context on the event and capture it in your event handler. Your event handler needs to be component agnostic though, meaning you need an event handler for all, i.e.

```
public void onValueChanged(@RequestParameter("newValue") Object newValue, int context) {
    ...
}
```

Then on each of your custom components add the context to the event, you did not show how you are currently generating the event so I am not able to tell you what to update.

Comment: This seems to be what Dmitry suggested, which worked (2.5 years ago)

Comment: Didn't notice the comment :/